# Why does $\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(3)=\ln(1+2+3)$?

Tags: logarithms, eulers-number-e

I was in a math class today and we were learning about logarithms. The teacher explained that:

$$\log(x+y) \neq \log(x) + \log(y)$$

And to prove this, decided to solve these two equations for the class:

$$\ln(1) + \ln(2) + \ln(3)$$

and

$$\ln(1+2+3).$$

For some reason, these two ln equations exactly equal each other. I divided one by the other with my calculator and the answer was 1. Is this pure coincidence? Or is there something interesting going on under the hood?

Comment: This is simply $\log(6)=\log(2\cdot 3)=\log(2)+\log(3)=\log(1)+\log(2)+\log(3)$. So there is only the functional equation "going on under the hood".

Comment: Because $1+2+3=1*2*3$

Comment: Your example shows that $\ln(x+y+z)\not=\ln(x)+\ln(y)+\ln(z)$ (assumed to be stated for all values of $x,y,z$) is false. What they really intended to teach in class is that the statement "For all $x,y$, $\ln(x+y)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$" is false. Equivalent, that the statement "There exist $x,y$ such that $\ln(x+y)\neq\ln(x)+\ln(y)$" is true.

Comment: You can also find examples for the case of two variables. For instance $\ln(2)+\ln(2)=\ln(2+2)$. Therefore the statement "For all $x,y$, $\ln(x+y)\neq\ln(x)+\ln(y)$" is also false.

Comment: @PC1 $\times$ is `\times`.

Answer (score 2):

We know that by the proprieties of $\ln(x)$:
$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(i)$$
Let $n=3$, we have that: $3!=1+2+3=6$, so:
$$\ln(3!)=\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(3)$$

Note that is a **very special case** because it is only verified for $n=\{1,2,3\}$. Namely:
$$1+2+\dots+n\leq n!\,\,\,\forall n \geq 4$$

Comment: "Not always true" seems like an understatement. :)

Comment: @prets: yeah. I have sligthly changed that. Thanks.

Comment: Oh no the phrasing was fine, I just think it's entertaining to say something that's only true two out of infinitely many times is "not always true". Perfectly accurate, but kind of burying the lead!

Comment: @prets: hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that $\log(x+y) \neq \log(x) + \log(y)$ is actually not true. There are actually infinitely many choices of $x$ and $y$ such that $\log(x+y) = \log(x)+\log(y).$ But for most choices we have an inequality. And that is the important: if you get $\log(x+y),$ do *not* think that it can be rewritten as $\log(x)+\log(y).$

In the same way, $\log(x+y+z)\neq\log(x)+\log(y)+\log(z)$ for most choices of $x,y,z.$ But as you have found, there are some choices for which we have equality, for example for $x=1,\ y=2,\ z=3,$ since both sides evaluate to $\log(6).$

Answer (score 1):

Do you see something there ?

$\begin{array}{l}
\ln(1+2+3)&=\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(3)\\
\ln(1+1+2+4)&=\ln(1)+\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(4)\\
\ln(1+1+1+2+5)&=\ln(1)+\ln(1)+\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(5)\\
\ln(1+1+1+1+2+6)&=\ln(1)+\ln(1)+\ln(1)+\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(6)\end{array}$

In fact this exploits the fact that $\ln(1)=0$ to get to $$\ln(2a)=\ln(2)+\ln(a)$$

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher wanted to show you that it can be dangerous to generalize based on a few cases. This example is made on purpose, based on the exceptional property $1+2+3=1\cdot2\cdot3$. (He could as well have used any solution to $x+y=xy$, but none are integer.)