# Spivak Calculus, Ch. 4 Graphs, Problem 18

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

This problem does not have solutions available in the solution manual.

We are asked to plot functions involving the term $\{x\}$, which is defined as the distance from $x$ to the nearest integer.

Here is my plot of $f(x)=\{x\}$

[image]

The plot of $\{nx\}$ looks similar: the nonzero points have their y coordinate multiplied by $n$.

Therefore, all the items in this question are variations of the graph above, where the nonzero points all have a y coordinate that is a multiple of the $\{x\}$ case.

For example, the last item of this question asks us to draw the graph of $$f(x) = \{x\} + \frac{1}{2}\{2x\}+\frac{1}{4}\{4x\}$$

We can simplify this to

$$f(x)=\{x\}+\{x\}+\{x\}=3\{x\}=\{3x\}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it is incorrect to move in the constant from outside. For instance if $x=1/3$ then $ \{ x \}=1/3$ but $\{3x\}=0$ so $\{x\}+\{x\}+\{x\}\ne \{3x\}$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Coincidentally, there is a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4317049/996269) emanating from the confusion that writing things like $\{x\}+\{x\}+\{x\}\neq\{3x\}$ unquantified can cause.

Comment: @Boxwood Not sure I understand your comment. I said "if $x=1/3$" so why would the last statement be unquantified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original question and attempt, I went through the question too quickly thinking it was easy. Here is my second attempt:

**i) $f(x)=\{x\}$**

[image]

**ii) $f(x)=\{2x\}$**

[image]

**iii) $f(x) = \{x\}+\frac{1}{2}\{2x\}$**

[image]

**iv) $f(x) = \{4x\}$**

[image]

**v) $f(x) = \{x\} + \frac{1}{2}\{2x\} +\frac{1}{4}\{4x\}$**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Why would $\frac12\{2x\}=\{x\}$? For instance, $\left\{\frac12\right\}=\frac12$, whereas you $\frac12\left\{2\times\frac12\right\}=\frac12\{1\}=0$.

It follows from this that you also do not have $\{2x\}=2\{x\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\{nx\}$ would have a higher frequency (by order n) than $\{x\}$ and have the same amplitude.

$n\{x\}$ would have higher amplitude but the same frequency.

$f(x) = {x} + \frac 12 {2x} + \frac 14 \{4x\}$

Break the domain up into intervals that are $\frac 18$ unit large.  Every time you cross an interval, at least one wave will flip from being a positive to a negative contributor to the slope.